# Google quantum supremacy experiment data

Tags: quantum-computing

I don't know if this is the right place to ask.

Still, I vaguely remember that there was a desire expressed by some people in this community to get access to the data of the 53 qubit Google quantum supremacy experiment, given that the data released for Google previous experiments, which was sometimes cited as evidence,  regarded much smaller number of qubits.

So I want to ask if since then the data for the 53 qubits original experiment was released and, if yes, where one can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be available on this [link](https://datadryad.org/stash/dataset/doi:10.5061/dryad.k6t1rj8).

Comment: thank you for the link.